# PostgreSQL - filter function for dates

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to use the built-in `filter` function in PostgreSQL to filter for a date range in order to sum only entries falling within this time-frame.
I cannot understand why the filter isn't being applied.
I am trying to filter for all product transactions that have a `created_at` date of the previous month (so in this case that were created in June 2017).

```
SELECT pt.created_at::date, pt.customer_id,
    sum(pt.amount/100::double precision) filter (where (date_part('month', pt.created_at) =date_part('month', NOW() - interval '1 month') and 
date_part('year', pt.created_at) = date_part('year', NOW()) ))

from 
    product_transactions pt
LEFT JOIN customers c
    ON c.id= pt.customer_id
GROUP BY pt.created_at::date,pt.customer_id
```

Please find my expected results (sum of the amount for each day in the previous month - for each customer_id if an entry for that day exists) and the actual results I get from the query - below (using `date_trunc`).
Expected results:

```
created_at| customer_id | amount
2017-06-30    1           220.5
2017-06-28    15            34.8
2017-06-28    12          157
2017-06-28    48          105.6
2017-06-27    332         425.8
2017-06-25    1           58.0
2017-06-25    23          22.5
2017-06-21    14          88.9
2017-06-17    2           34.8
2017-06-12    87          250
2017-06-05    48          135.2
2017-06-05    12          95.7
2017-06-01    44          120
```

Results:

```
created_at| customer_id | amount
2017-06-30    1           220.5
2017-06-28    15            34.8
2017-06-28    12          157
2017-06-28    48          105.6
2017-06-27    332         425.8
2017-06-25    1           58.0
2017-06-25    23          22.5
2017-06-21    14          88.9
2017-06-17    2           34.8
2017-06-12    87          250
2017-06-05    48          135.2
2017-06-05    12          95.7
2017-06-01    44          120
2017-05-30    XX          YYY
2017-05-25    XX          YYY
2017-05-15    XX          YYY
2017-04-30    XX          YYY
2017-03-02    XX          YYY
2016-11-02    XX          YYY
```

The actual results give me the sum for all dates in the database, so no date time-frame is being applied in the query for a reason I cannot understand. I'm seeing dates that are both not for June 2017 and also from previous years.

Comment: could you please elaborate the post with data samples and expected result

Answer (score 0):

Use `date_trunc(..)` function:

```
SELECT pt.created_at::date, pt.customer_id, c.name,
    sum(pt.amount/100::double precision) filter (where date_trunc('month', pt.created_at) = date_trunc('month', NOW() - interval '1 month'))
from 
    product_transactions pt
LEFT JOIN customers c
    ON c.id= pt.customer_id
GROUP BY pt.created_at::date
```

Comment: shouldn't the year be filtered as well, as I want to account for all entries in June 2017 and not previous years?

Comment: `date_trunc('month', ..)` will return values like `2017-07-01 00:00:00`

Comment: So it will keep knowledge about year and month, but throw out anything else. It's exactly what you need AFAICS.

Comment: I've tried this approach and the filter isn't being applied in this case either. I'm seeing entries both from months greater than the previous and from the last years. `created_at` is a `timestamp`. All references to the `created_at` field i've left as a `timestamp` and have not cast to `date`. Could that cause an issue?

Comment: So you just need to filter out rows? The use `WHERE` clause, put it between `FROM` and `GROUP BY`.

Comment: how come is the filter function not working? I've added the `created_at` field in the query so that I can understand what the query is doing or not doing. I basically want to see the sum `amount` for each customer in the previous month - so how much each customer spent during the previous month.

Comment: to answer your question. Using `WHERE` instead of the `FILTER` function will require me to write three sub-queries as I want to have the total amount per customer for the past three months dynamically. Meaning I will re-run the query continuously.